# Best practices or patterns for "Saved Search" and "Edit Saved Search"?

Tags: search, search-results

I have been tasked with redesigning our saved search function, as it has been deemed confusing (and I can't find another site that works like ours does currently). Are there any standard ways of handling both **Saving a search** and then allowing people to **edit and save changes to a search**? I have checked out what Ebay does. Is that fairly standard?

Edited to include the ebay (UK) example:
[image]

Comment: Hi Anna. Are you able to share a sketch or mockup of what you have currently, or what approaches you're considering? I'm not familiar with how Ebay handles this. Could you describe their approach as well? If you would, please [edit] your question to include some of these additional details. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a sketch or rough wireframe that you have thought of (Not eBay example)?

Comment: The term "search" is ambiguous. Do you mean a [query or a report?](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTQPQ_7.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.imp_mast.7.5.0.doc/imp_mast_id9039TheDifferenceBetweenQueriesandReports.html)

Answer (score 1):

A few things, first a few functionalities clarifications

1. Save search as... Give the saved query a name.
2. Enable the user to delete the saved search.
3. Display the time stamp when the save was created/modified.In case hell need another clue to when and why it was saved.
4. You can also add the searched terms.If the user searched for ice cream, november, vanilla, display values.This helps in recognition instead of recall.

You can look into TFS/jira and these to see the saved query functionality. Linkedin also used to have this feature on their desktop.